# Knockout subscribe event fired twice

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using KO observable array and i am trying to change one of its observable field in its own .subscribe method, which causes firing same event twice.
How can i avoid this ? 
Code below

```
        $.each(self.PricingList(), function (i, pricing) {

        var previousValue = pricing.Currency().code();

        pricing.Currency().code.subscribe(function () {
            ShowConfirmation(null, 'Are you sure ?',
                function () {
                    // will be executed if user click on Yes
                },function () {
                     // Will be executed if user clicks No 
                    // How can i restore previous value ?
                   pricing.Currency().code(previousValue);
                   // the moment i change currency code's value its showing me confirmation dialog again, which i want to avoid.
                });
        });
```

Comment: i am amused why you are doing so ? looping through a array and showing some confirmation box ? what i didnt get here is you went on to say if user choose `cancel` observable inside array should bind with previous value ? how can this be happening . sorry to say so it total rubbish way of even thinking , cheers

Comment: you can change a observable of same inside subscribe based on your confirm box via `retun` . i made a sample fiddle which does that when you change something it will ask you to change/revert .needed i can share it up

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.each(self.PricingList(), function (i, pricing) {    
        pricing.Currency().code.subscribe(function (previousValue) {
            ShowConfirmation(null, 'Are you sure ?',
                function () {

                },function () {
                   pricing.Currency().code(previousValue);// this line calls subscribe method again because the value in this observable changes, so try to remove this line from here.

                });
        }, null, "beforeChange");
```

Source: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Comment: this is surely not an answer, I do not want to subscribe to the beforeChange event.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't directly an answer to your question but I believe it will solve the underlying problem if I have assumed correctly: you are trying to make an optionally-undoable change.

If you look at this [blog post](http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2013/05/29/editable-object-graphs-in-knockout/) it describes an approach where you use a wrapper (similar to an extender) around the observer that provides `beginEdit` and `cancelEdit` functions that can be invoked as required.

The source code for this is available in [this Github repo](https://github.com/stevegreatrex/ko.plus).